# PHPTAL - No template file specified

Tags: php, phptal

I have an identical site running on two different servers, and for some reason I am presented with the following error message on one of the servers when I either login or logout of the CMS on the site.

```
PHPTAL Exception

No template file specified

In /usr/share/pear/PHPTAL.php line 1138

#0 /usr/share/pear/PHPTAL.php(801): PHPTAL->findTemplate()
#1 /usr/share/pear/PHPTAL.php(821): PHPTAL->setCodeFile()
#2 /usr/share/pear/PHPTAL.php(667): PHPTAL->prepare()
#3 /var/www/html/example.co.uk/main.php(318): PHPTAL->execute()
#4 /var/www/html/example.co.uk/main.php(2746): main->tal()
#5 {main}
```

Any idea what could be causing it? I'm not familiar with PHPTAL, I am just trying to migrate the site to a new server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need check the path of the template in the CMS

Answer (score 0):

It means that you passed `NULL` argument to PHPTAL constructor instead of template path, and/or haven't called `setTemplate()` nor `setSource()`.

Check logic in your application that selects which template should be output (maybe it's dependent on app configuration that differs between servers?)

Answer (score 0):

Do a var_dump of the template repositories before the line that renders the template file (e.g. display()) by using the getTemplateRepositories() method.

It will print out your current template repositories path if you've properly set it somewhere. Your template file path should be relative to the template repositories path.